# Lua - Request works via curl, but not via Lua (Lua socket)?

Tags: api, lua, luasocket

I’m trying to interact with the Sipgate api (https://developer.sipgate.io/ ) using Lua, and an example they provide for authentication uses Curl, which works. (Not my b64 user/pass)

```
curl \
  --request GET \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Basic Sm9objp0b3BzZWNyZXQ=" \
  https://api.sipgate.com/v2/account
```

But when I try it via Lua, I get the following error.
Does anyone have an idea of what i’m missing

**Message/response..**

ok      1
statusCode     301
statusText     HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
headers:     table: 0x2692948
location     https://api.sipgate.com:80/v2/account/
connection     close
content-length     0

*Lua code used..*

```
local https = require "ssl.https"
local mime = require("mime")
local http = require "socket.http"
local data = ""
local username = "user"
local password = "pass"

local function collect(chunk)
  if chunk ~= nil then
    data = data .. chunk
    end
  return true
end

local ok, statusCode, headers, statusText = http.request {
  method = "GET",
  url = "https://api.sipgate.com/v2/account",
  headers = {
    ["Accept"] = "application/json",
    ["Authorization"] = "Basic " .. (mime.b64(username ..":" .. password)),
    },
  sink = collect
}

--debug - 
print("enc64", mime.b64(username ..":" .. password))
print("ok\t",         ok);
print("statusCode", statusCode)
print("statusText", statusText)
print("headers:", headers)

print("data", data)
```

Comment: Confirm that the socket library supports http**s**. If it's a basic socket library, it may not support TLS.

Comment: It seems to via ‘local https = require "ssl.https" and I’ve tried both - sorry I should have included that - I’ll update the original post..

Comment: Hi all - any other ideas ?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?